# How can all the information that we, humans, generate be carried by a single laser beam?

Tags: optics, laser, information

In the book of *How the laser happended*, by C.H.Townes, at page 5 the author states that

> Lasers provide an unsurpassed medium for communication. One laser beam can, in principle, carry all the information that is passing back and forth right now among all the people and computers in the world. The signals from all the telephone lines, all the television stations, all the radio stations, all the talk and music and digitized information-all could be packed into just one laser beam. This possibility has not yet been achieved. but we are well on the way to do so and already use remarkable rates of communication by laser beams.

How can all the information that we, humans, generate be carried by a single laser beam?

Comment: To be fair, when Townes wrote the book there was a LOT less data being slung around...

Comment: @JonCuster a fair comment; but the main question is not whether it is true or not, but rather how it can be done from a physicist perspective, so it is a conceptual question.

Comment: Trans-ocean fibers carry a whole lot of data riding on a laser beam.

Comment: @JonCuster how?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber-optic_cable and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber-optic_communication are places to start.